# Supervisord runs ssserver but reports an error on CentOS?

Tags: supervisord, shadowsocks

I have the following Supervisord setup, `/etc/supervisord.conf`:

```
...
[program:shadowsocks]
command=ssserver -c ~/config.json
autorestart=true
user=nobody
...
```

`/etc/rc.d/init.d/supervisord`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# /etc/rc.d/init.d/supervisord
#
# Supervisor is a client/server system that
# allows its users to monitor and control a
# number of processes on UNIX-like operating
# systems.
#
# chkconfig: - 64 36
# description: Supervisor Server
# processname: supervisord

# Source init functions
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

prog="supervisord"

prefix="/usr/"
exec_prefix="${prefix}"
prog_bin="${exec_prefix}/bin/supervisord"
PIDFILE="/var/run/$prog.pid"

start()
{
       echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
       daemon $prog_bin --pidfile $PIDFILE
       [ -f $PIDFILE ] && success $"$prog startup" || failure $"$prog startup"
       echo
}

stop()
{
       echo -n $"Shutting down $prog: "
       [ -f $PIDFILE ] && killproc $prog || success $"$prog shutdown"
       echo
}

case "$1" in

 start)
   start
 ;;

 stop)
   stop
 ;;

 status)
       status $prog
 ;;

 restart)
   stop
   start
 ;;

 *)
   echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
 ;;

esac
```

I then do the following to set it up and start it:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.d/init.d/supervisord
$ sudo chkconfig --add supervisord
$ sudo chkconfig supervisord on
$ sudo service supervisord start
```

Afterwards everything is OK. Now when I start `shadowsocks`:

```
supervisorctl start shadowsocks
```

It reports an error:

```
shadowsocks: ERROR (abnormal termination)
```

However if I executes directly:

```
ssserver -c ~/config.json
```

it works well. Why won't this work with `supervisord`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, `supervisor` does not support tidle `~` expansion, `~/config.json` is treated as literal.

You should change `~/config.json` to its absolute path `/path/to/config.json` and make sure it can be accessed by `nobody`.

More about supervisor configuration, see [here](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings).